# Cannot detect second display - Ubuntu 17.04*

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, 17.04

I have problem to detect second monitor on my PC.

I work on Ubuntu 17.04 LTS , I don't know why. I connect by HDMI cable (1st monitor) & by DisplayPort to DVI (2nd monitor).

**My graphics card is Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)**

after   `xrandr` I have received:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: I need some more information to understand what is going on. Open a terminal and run `xrandr`. Make sure both monitors are plugged in before running the command. Add the output of the command to your question.

Comment: Sorry , I have updated system to 17.04 LTS and have the same problem.

  **bold**   Display card : Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)

Comment: Is there a chance it is a hardware problem? Do you have another OS installed to test your hdmi port and the cable?

Comment: First (HDMI) port is ok , but 2nd (DVI) cannot be detected.

I've got only one HDMI, what a pity...

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same issue.
one day, cuda went wrong and told me that can not communicate with nvidia driver.
after I reinstall the nvidia driver.
the system cannot detect the 2nd monitor.
and I solved the issue by removing the following line：

> Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"

in /etc/X11/xorg.conf

hope this will be helpful.